# How to align two strings in a HStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

currently I have a SwiftUI view which is displaying me "opening hours for a bank". The dates are on the left side and the hours are on the right side. Is working well, but I have an issue. If there are 2 hours for a single date, and the second hour will be shown to the next date. If there are 2 hours for a date, I do not want a padding between them, but only after that. I will attach a screenshot for a better understanding. Code is bellow :

```
struct OpeningHours: View {
    let titles: [String]
    let hours: [String]
    
    init(titles: [String], hours: [String]) {
        self.titles = titles
        self.hours = hours
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: .zero) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: .zero) {
                ForEach(titles, id: \.self) { title in
                    Text(title)
                        .rchFont(.rchBody)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.trailing, .md)
                        .padding(.bottom, RCHPadding.xs.size + RCHPadding.sm.size)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: .zero) {
                ForEach(hours, id: \.self) { hour in
                    Text(hour)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .rchFont(.rchBodyBold)
                        .padding(.bottom, RCHPadding.xs.size + RCHPadding.sm.size)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, .xs)
    }
}
```

```
"specialOpeningTimes": [
          {
            "openingTimeType": "ONE_DATE",
            "fromDate": "2023-10-09",
            "toDate": null,
            "timeRanges": [
              {
                "fromTime": "09:00",
                "toTime": "12:00"
              },
                           {
                "fromTime": "09:00",
                "toTime": "12:00"
              }
            ]
```

[image: Opening hours photo]

Comment: You should have one array for both values and one ForEach loop and use a HStack for each row

Comment: Redesign your data. You have titles and hours completely disconnected from each other - so there's no way to make it right in this design. Instead, design a struct that includes title and 1 or more opening hours. Have an array of such structs. Then display every item as HStack, and the whole set as List.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson won't help: as per explanation there can be "2 hours for a single date", so 2 arrays just won't work, because there's no way to know how they are related. OP really needs a proper struct for each row.

Comment: I would want to specify that in my viewModel, I have one function that retrieves all the hours, and one function that retrieves all the dates.

I will update my question with the json

Comment: Are you responsible for the JSON? If yes, don’t send multiple identical time ranges. If not, filter the duplicates.

Comment: @vadian Is not about the duplicates, here is just an example I've mapped locally, can be anything there.

Comment: Can you show what your expected result looks like, perhaps by doing some image editing on the screenshot?

Comment: I totally agree with the suggestion to lay out the *table* horizontally by putting the information of one row into one object.